# Running Multiple For Loops at a time

Tags: python

I am trying to run Multiple for Loops in my code. For some reasons it is misbehaving.

Here is the approach: i'm calling the `function1()`

```
def function1():
  all_cohorts = get_all_cohorts()
  for chrt in all_cohorts:
    emit_event()
    #end of for loop
  # this code should be called after the for loop is done
  call_for_members_of_cohort(all_cohorts) 

def call_for_members_of_cohort(all_cohorts):
  for chrt in all_cohorts:
    get_members_of_cohort(chrt)

def get_members_of_cohort(cohort):
  users = cohort.users.all()
  for u in users:
    emit_event()
```

This is the whole flow of the approach. for some reasons the loops runs 2 times. for example `call_for_members_of_cohort` function called with 2 cohorts and `get_members_of_cohort` will run 2 times. but instead it runs more than 2 times.

is there anything wrong with the approach? can anyone suggest me to solve this or suggest me an alternamte approach?

Comment: There are 3 loops in your code, which of them run only twice when you expect them to run <some number other than 2 times>?  What is `len(all_cohorts)`?

Comment: Please clarify what "misbehaving" means; be specific.

Comment: The problem is there are `2 cohorts`. `cohort1` has 1 member and `cohort2` has 5 members. for some reasons `cohort2` members function runs twice

Comment: @jedwards updated the question

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve] that we can run, that demonstrates the problem, instead of trying to explain it in words?